# How to load the posts in blog post index page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a 6 posts in wordpress admin backend and displayed on blog post page there is no issue. I have some conditions to display posts.

Steps:

1. First compare each post_title of wp_posts with the wp_terms name . If comparison match get the category id of post_title and store the category id list into an separate array list and not match category id of post into another array list.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?.

Comment: I'm new to wordpress. I didn't tired anything

Comment: Can any one please help me out?

Comment: i thought you need to surf in internet. may be you will get some idea. see this one may help you- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category.

conditional tags ref. - https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags